# Сериализация и передача объека по сети (EOFException)

Tags: сокет, сериализация, десериализация

Всем доброго времени суток! Столкнулся с проблемой при упаковке и передаче объекта между клиентом(Android) и Сервером(Java).

Кусок клиентской части(упаковка и пересылка):
@Override
    public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {

```
    Point point = new Point(event.getX(), event.getY());

    switch(event.getAction()){

        case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:

            try{

                ObjectOutputStream outputStream = new ObjectOutputStream(this.clientConnection.getOutputStream());

                outputStream.writeObject(point);
                outputStream.flush();
                outputStream.close();

            }catch(IOException e){
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

        break;
    }
    return true;
}
```

Серверная часть:
public void run(){

```
    System.err.println("Запущен поток выполнения для Клиента #" + this.clientID);

    try{

        // Обертка потока
        ObjectInputStream inputStream = new ObjectInputStream(this.clientSocket.getInputStream());

        try{

            while(true){

                // Десериализация объека
                Point point = (Point) inputStream.readObject();

                System.err.println(point.x + " : " + point.y);

            }

        }catch(ClassNotFoundException e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }catch(EOFException e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }catch(IOException e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    } 
}
```

Лог:

> Запущен поток выполнения для Клиента #0
>
> 26.444906:275.00372 java.io.EOFException  at java.io.ObjectInputStream$BlockDataInputStream.peekByte(Unknown
>   Source)   at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(Unknown Source)    at
>   java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(Unknown Source)  at
>   com.kmaks.mouseserver.Client.run(Client.java:72)  at
>   java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`EOFException` означает, что поток, читающий из сокета, получил EOF на вход. Это нормальное поведение, так как в клиенте вы закрываете сокет вызовом `outputStream.close();`. Если вы поймали это исключение, считайте, что клиент завершился нормально, и закрывайте сокет со своей стороны. [Вот так правильно:](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3956163/does-closing-the-inputstream-of-a-socket-also-close-the-socket-connection)

```
catch(EOFException e){
    this.clientSocket.close();
    // и выходить из сервера, или открывать и ждать следующий сеанс связи
}
```

Comment: Где-то я слышал выражение: "Программирование на исключениях", мол это не хорошо?

Comment: Это Java, ЕМНИП с ней по-другому не получается.

Answer (score 0):

Рекомендую при получении объекта из потока записывать его в отдельный объект класса Object, т.е.

```
Object obj = objectInputStream.readObject();
```

В дальнейшем осуществляйте преобразования над этим объектом.